# Open all .doc files in a folder and apply the code

Tags: vba

This is the last step of my work. I have designed a code to retrieve tables from a Word document.
I have written a code which works for each individual Word document. I have thousands of Word documents and I would love to automate the process.

In other words, I would like to run the code for all the .doc files in the same folder but I can't seem to get my head around it.

The (beginning) code looks like this:

```
Sub importTableDataWord()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'We declare object variables for Word Application and document
Dim wdApp As Object, wddoc As Object
'Declare a string variable to access our Word document
Dim strDocName As String

'Designate Word
'Error handling
On Error Resume Next
'Create a Word application if Word is not already open
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wdApp.Visible = True
strDocName = "C:\Users\PDX\Documents\CBA01.doc"
'Check relevant directory for relevant document
'If not found then inform the user and close program
If Dir(strDocName) = "" Then
    MsgBox "The file " & strDocName & vbCrLf & _
    "was not found in the folder path" & vbCrLf & _
    "C:\our-inventory\.", _
    vbExclamation, _
    "Sorry, that document name does not exist."
Exit Sub
End If

'Open/activate the designated Word
wdApp.Activate
Set wddoc = wdApp.Documents(strDocName)
If wddoc Is Nothing Then Set wddoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(strDocName)
wddoc.Activate

'Define variables to access the tables in the word document
Dim Tble As Integer
Dim rowWd As Long
Dim colWd As Integer
Dim x As Long, y As Long
x = 1
y = 1


''''' FIRST LINE, FIRST TABLE

'Count nb of tables in my Word
With wddoc
Tble = wddoc.Tables.Count
    If Tble = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Tables found in the Word document", vbExclamation, "No Tables to Import"
Exit Sub
End If

'Start the looping process to access tables and their rows, columns
For i = 1 To 1
    With .Tables(i)
    For colWd = 1 To .Columns.Count
    Cells(x, y) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(1, colWd).Range.Text)
    'Access next column until the end
    y = y + 1
    Next colWd
    'go to next row and start from column 1
    y = 1
    x = x + 1
End With
Next
End With

wdApp.Quit
End Sub
```

I was thinking to use something similar as below but can't find a way to create a loop to apply the code!

```
'set folder where all the .doc are located
myFolder = "C:\Users\PDX\Documents\"
strFile = Dir(myFolder & "\*.doc", vbNormal)
While strFrile <> ""
Set wddoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=myFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=True)

'Open/activate the designated Word
wdApp.Activate
Set wddoc = wdApp.Documents(strDocName)
If wddoc Is Nothing Then Set wddoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(strDocName)
wddoc.Activate
```

But I also thought of creating a sub calling my main sub:

```
Sub testhello()
Dim file
Dim path As String


path = "C:\Users\PDX\Documents\"

file = Dir(path & "*.doc")
Do While file <> ""
Documents.Open Filename:=path & file

Call importTableDataWord

ActiveDocument.Save
ActiveDocument.Close

file = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
Ideally, 1 w
```

**Ideally,** the loop would be such that 1 word table retrieved = 1 spreadsheet, OR, the next table retrieved would appear after the last row.

Any feedback appreciated. If you know about some of it, or have any hint, feel free to propose!

Comment: have you used my answer below ?

Answer (score 1):

I would use your second approach, Have a loop that scans all word files in a folder, and every times it finds a new word documents it calls another Sub that performs all the tasks that you want.

**First Sub**: loops through all Word files in a Folder

```
Option Explicit

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim path As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim myFolder As FileDialog
Dim wdApp As Object, wddoc As Object


Sub Loop_AllWordFiles_inFolder()

Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
Set myFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With myFolder
    .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    path = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

' if the User select "Cancel"
NextCode:
path = path
If path = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

' Target File Extension
myExtension = "*.doc"

' Target Path with Ending Extention
myFile = Dir(path & myExtension)
' Loop through all doc files in folder
Do While myFile <> ""
    Set wddoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=path & myFile)

    ' HERE you call your other routine
    Call importTableDataWord

    wddoc.Close SaveChanges:=True
    myFile = Dir
Loop

MsgBox "Finished scanning all files in Folder " & path

ResetSettings:

' Reset Macro Optimization Settings
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set wdApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Second Sub**: just use the rest of your existing code here (where you perform all your data import from all tables.

```
Sub importTableDataWord()

' put all you code here...

End Sub
```

Comment: Weirdly enough it takes ages to load (even for two word docs) and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @pdx what is not working for you? were you able to get the tables ? did your previous code worked on a single word file ? I've tested this code, and I was able to copy each word file I opened and also the number of pages per file. So the Loop part of opening all word files in a selected folder works.

Answer (score 0):

The following lines in the code need an appropriate reference or driver to install. if you couldn't find them, you can delete all the lines bellow from your code. Then you will see it works for you.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```